# Issues using the rolling feature of pandas with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I tried using `rolling(4).sum().shift(-3)`
but I run into an issue where it keeps adding because I don't have a condition where it stops to check if the movement has changed. I tried groupby but it throws an error as well. Any advice?

| movement | value |
| --- | --- |
| right | 2 |
| right | 1 |
| right | 3 |
| right | 1 |
| right | 1 |
| right | 1 |
| right | 1 |
| right | 1 |
| Left | 5 |
| Left | 4 |
| Left | 2 |
| Left | 1 |
| Left | 1 |
| Left | 1 |
| Left | 1 |
| Left | 1 |

What I want to get is the following:

| movement | value | rolling value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| right | 2 | 7 |
| right | 1 | 6 |
| right | 3 | 6 |
| right | 1 | 4 |
| right | 1 | 4 |
| right | 1 | nan |
| right | 1 | nan |
| right | 1 | nan |
| Left | 5 | 12 |
| Left | 4 | 8 |
| Left | 2 | 5 |
| Left | 1 | 4 |
| Left | 1 | 4 |
| Left | 1 | nan |
| Left | 1 | nan |
| Left | 1 | nan |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a [`FixedForwardWindowIndexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer.html) with an offset of -3 as the `window` instead of shifting after the fact, and [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) to remove the additional index in movement, but keep the index alignment of the DataFrame:

```
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=4, offset=-3)
df['rolling value'] = (
    df.groupby('movement')['value'].rolling(window=indexer).sum().droplevel(0)
)
```

`df`:

```
   movement  value  rolling value
0     right      2            7.0
1     right      1            6.0
2     right      3            6.0
3     right      1            4.0
4     right      1            4.0
5     right      1            NaN
6     right      1            NaN
7     right      1            NaN
8      Left      5           12.0
9      Left      4            8.0
10     Left      2            5.0
11     Left      1            4.0
12     Left      1            4.0
13     Left      1            NaN
14     Left      1            NaN
15     Left      1            NaN
```

---

Just the produced Series:

```
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=4, offset=-3)
print(df.groupby('movement')['value'].rolling(window=indexer).sum())
```

```
movement    
Left      8     12.0
          9      8.0
          10     5.0
          11     4.0
          12     4.0
          13     NaN
          14     NaN
          15     NaN
right     0      7.0
          1      6.0
          2      6.0
          3      4.0
          4      4.0
          5      NaN
          6      NaN
          7      NaN
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

The first level (`movement`) is the issue in assigning the values back to the DataFrame (and the reason why `groupby` wouldn't work).

`droplevel(0)` makes the Series :

```
8     12.0
9      8.0
10     5.0
11     4.0
12     4.0
13     NaN
14     NaN
15     NaN
0      7.0
1      6.0
2      6.0
3      4.0
4      4.0
5      NaN
6      NaN
7      NaN
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

This will align correctly with the DataFrame.

---

Slightly different DataFrame used to show the sums:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'movement': ['right', 'right', 'right', 'right', 'right', 'right', 'right',
                 'right', 'Left', 'Left', 'Left', 'Left', 'Left', 'Left',
                 'Left', 'Left'],
    'value': [2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
})
```

Comment: ah so that's why you can just `droplevel` without `sort=False`, nice explanation

Comment: Thank you @tdy Yeah index alignment is one of those things it's either _super_ helpful or it's in the way.

Comment: I think i need to update pandas. I get the error: AttributeError: module 'pandas.api.indexers' has no attribute 'FixedForwardWindowIndexer'

Comment: @joshuah9 apologies. That was my mistake `BaseIndex` was introduced in `1.0.0`. `FixedForwardWindowIndexer` wasn't added until `1.1.0` [What’s new in 1.1.0 (July 28, 2020) Other enhancements](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#other-enhancements)